# How to specify the mode-name displayed in the buffer pop-up list?

Tags: major-mode, nxml

I'm working on a couple of XML-format major modes, both of which are derived modes based on nXML, and I cannot get Emacs to display the mode names -- either in the minibuffer or in the buffer-list pop-up.

Everything I've read suggests that setting the mode name should work with:

```
(define-derived-mode fontfile-ttx-mode nxml-mode "FontTools TTX"
  "Major mode for editing FontTools TTX files."
;; [... eliding other simple stuff ...]
)
```

But the minibuffer still shows (nXML Valid) ....  In addition, the buffer menu pop-up labels buffers using this mode as 'SGML'. I also saw a suggestion to add an explicit name line, a la:

(setq mode-name "FontTools TTX")

But that changes nothing.  The TTX example is just one; I would like both of my nXML-derived modes to be labeled correctly (ie, not lumped together as SGML) so that the user can easily distinguish between them.  And, of course, I just want to figure out what the problem is.

These approaches work fine with modes derived from fundamental mode; is something else going on just for an nXML-derived mode?

Thanks

Comment: This question risks getting closed unless you update it using proper emacs terms. Please refer to [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLine) and update the question as needed. To me, it seems like you are referring to the *major mode name* as *pop-up label* and *minor mode list* as *minibuffer*. It would be even better if you can put a screenshot with annotations of your observations.

Answer (score 1):

1. The question is not clear.  I think perhaps you mean "mode-line" when you say "minibuffer".  If so, please edit the question to make it clear.
2. Evaluating the code you presented, and then using it by `M-x fontfile-ttx-mode`, I do not see a problem with the major-mode lighter in the mode line.  It says `FontTools TTX`.  And that is the value of variable `mode-name` - there is no need to set it separately.
3. It's also not clear what you mean by "the buffer-list pop-up" and "the buffer pop-up list".

I suspect that you are not telling us everything.  Please clarify the question, or it risks being closed as unclear.

Comment: 1. Fine. modeline.
2. Did you open a TTX file?
3. This is quite clear: C-leftmouse pops up the list of currently open buffers.

I am "telling you everything." That final comment does not advance the discussion.

Comment: 1) Yes, I visited a buffer named foo.txx (and did the same thing for foo.xml). The mode line lighter is named `FontTools TTX`, and its `mouse-1` menu has these two submenus: `XML` and `Text`. Seems fine to me. 2) I'm still guessing that you have **not** specified everything. Something at your end makes you see something different from (a) what I see and (b) what you expected to see. Try debugging - I'd be willing to bet (if I were a gambler) that you have indeed left something out of your "clear" recipe to reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) Try (without the debugger) using your code with a trivial TXX file, or even an empty file `foo.txx`. 2) If that doesn't work either, try `M-x debug-on-entry fontfile-ttx-mode` and walk through the debugger. See what happens. A wild guess is that an error is being raised that prevents the mode from being established correctly.

Comment: If I evaluate the code above and activate the mode, the modeline cotains `(FontTools TXX Valid)` which is expected. If you just want to get rid of the `Valid` part have the mode set `mode-line-process` to nil. Take a look at the value of `mode-line-process` in a xml buffer to see why `Valid` shows up.

Comment: @JordonBiondo: I didn't get the impression from the description that the presence of `Valid` is unwanted. The complaint seems to be that the OP does not get (as you and I do), `FontTools TXX` in the mode-line.

Comment: Same for me, `FontTools TTX Valid` shows in the mode line if I define the mode using the snippet of code in the question. If I have several such files open, `mouse-buffer-menu` groups them under `FontTools TTX`. Is it possible you previously added an entry to `auto-mode-alist` to open ttx files in nxml mode? With `emacs -Q` a .ttx file opens in Fundamental mode for me. If I open a couple and manually put them in nxml mode, the mouse buffer menu groups them under `SGML` as the OP described.

Comment: @glucas No; auto-mode-alist entry is specifically tied to .ttx. The entire mode is much longer, of course, containing the regexps for all of the keyword highlighting and so on.  However, I think that any testing you do must use an actual TTX file not an empty file, since whatever the issue is, nXML is seizing control....

Comment: Not sure what else to try, since several of us have now been unable to reproduce the problem. I've tried enabling this ttx mode with a non-empty file and don't see an issue. From what you are describing it could be that `nxml-mode` is being chosen instead when you open a .ttx file, but then you would not see any of the other expected behavior of your custom mode (highlighting, etc) and would be able to test this theory by simply enabling ttx mode manually.